# Task :react-native-workers:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle

I am trying to run a `react-native` android application using `react-native-cli`, whenever I try to run the application using react-native run-android I am getting following error,

```
Task :react-native-workers:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

is this related to Gralde or react-native?